# PHP search by name and last name or middle name

Tags: php, mysql

I have names like this:

"John Martin Bud"
"John Erik"

Ok. Imagine that somebody search for "john bud" OR "bud john".

I want to return "JOHN MARTIN BUD"

But the way I'm doing returns both "JOHN MARTIN BUD" & "JOHN ERIK"

I'm doing this:

```
$keywords = $_POST['campobusca'];
$keywords=explode(' ',$keywords); 
$string = implode("%' AND name LIKE '%", $keywords);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE '%$string'";
.
.
.
```

How can I perform this search?

Thanks

Comment: did you made typo ? nome?

Comment: Reverted back to original question, as we can see what you're trying and assist further with your debugging. Removing that information would be silly

Comment: what you need is fuzzy matching

Comment: maybe you need to split the name like first_name and last_name as separated attributes. Another option is search by just one word and change the query `... LIKE %$string% ...`. Or use the `SOUNDEX` function

Comment: at some point you edited the question changing `OR` (incorrect) with `AND` (correct) where you build the query. what is the problem now?

Comment: @Guido: The problem is "using" AND a search for "BUD JOHN" returns empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small typo:

```
$keywords = "john doe";
$keywords=explode(' ',$keywords); 
$string = implode("%' AND name LIKE '%", $keywords);
echo "SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE '%$string'";
```

will output:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE '%john%' AND name LIKE '%doe'
```

You need to the missing trailing wildcard in the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE '%$string%'";
                                                     ^
```